# Discord.py Rate Limit

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

This used to work for changing my bot's activity every 5 minutes, but now the terminal is spammed with this rate limit warning:

`WARNING  discord.gateway WebSocket in shard ID None is ratelimited, waiting 0.00 seconds`

The number it gives can also sometimes be around 57-59 seconds. I wouldn't think 5 minutes is too short of a timer to change something about a bot, I've seen other bots change their profile picture every couple minutes or so, which is way more demanding on a server I would assume. Is there a better way of doing this? Code below.

```
actaray = ["PcktWtchr's Videos", "Cams", "and Listening Always", "or Listening or Both"]

# Start-up
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as {0.user}'.format(bot))
    while True:
        await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name=random.choice(actaray)))
        asyncio.sleep(300)
```

Like I said, this used to work as far as I remember. The wait time used to be 60 seconds, but since it gave me the rate limit, I increased it to 300 because I assumed it was too quick. The problem still persisted.

Comment: As written on the documentation [on_ready](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_ready), *this event is not guaranteed to only be called once*, which could lead to rate limits.

Comment: I would edit the title to be more specific as to not have this be closed as a duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your current code, you have an infinite loop that changes the bot's presence every 5 minutes. While changing the presence every 5 minutes may not seem excessive, the loop runs continuously without any delays, and this can lead to hitting the rate limits. Modify your code to introduce a delay between presence changes using `asyncio.sleep`.

Try this modified code, and see if it works:

```py
actaray = ["PcktWtchr's Videos", "Cams", "and Listening Always", "or Listening or Both"]

# Start-up
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as {0.user}'.format(bot))
    while True:
        await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name=random.choice(actaray)))
        await asyncio.sleep(300)  # delay between presence changes

@bot.event
async def on_error(event, *args, **kwargs):
    if isinstance(args[0], discord.HTTPException) and args[0].status == 429:
        # Rate limit encountered
        retry_after = args[0].headers.get("Retry-After")
        if retry_after:
            await asyncio.sleep(int(retry_after) + 1)  # Wait for the suggested time before retrying
        else:
            await asyncio.sleep(5)  # Fallback to a reasonable delay if Retry-After is not provided
    else:
        # Handle errors if they occur
        print(f"An error occurred: {args[0]}")
```

Comment: I'm gonna be real and say I have no idea what the code you added means, but it 100% worked. Appreciate the help!

Comment: This doesn't solve the issue that the on_ready event fires multiple times.